# Using data from JSON files as references to data from other JSON files

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I am trying to make a website for a tabletop game a friend of mine created, and I want to store all the data in JSON files and pull up the data in HTML files with Javascript. I want to, for example, store each class in a separate file, with its skill list (only listing the skill name and level learned in this file) included in the file, and a master list of all skills, their costs, and their descriptions in another file. Basically, I want to treat two or more JSON files like linked tables in a database.

In this example, this is what would be found in the class's file:

```
 {
        "name": "Class 1",
        "skills": [
            {
                "name": "Skill 1",
                "level": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Skill 2",
                "level": 2
            },
            {
                "name": "Skill 3",
                "level": 3
            }
        ]
    }
```

And this is the master skill file:

```
    {
        "skills": [
            {
                "name": "Skill 1",
                "desc": "This is the first skill.",
                "cost": "1 MP"
            },
            {
                "name": "Skill 2",
                "desc": "This is the second skill.",
                "cost": "2 HP"
            },
            {
                "name": "Skill 3",
                "desc": "This is the third skill.",
                "cost": "3 Gold"
            },
            {
                "name": "Skill 4",
                "desc": "This is a skill from a different class.",
                "cost": "All MP"
            }
        ]
    }
```

And I want the HTML file to output something like this, using these two separate JSON files:

```
<h1>Class 1</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Skill 1</td>
            <td>Level 1</td>
            <td>1 MP</td>
            <td>This is the first skill.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Skill 2</td>
            <td>Level 2</td>
            <td>2 HP</td>
            <td>This is the second skill.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Skill 3</td>
            <td>Level 3</td>
            <td>3 Gold</td>
            <td>This is the third skill.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Can this be done? And if so, how?

Comment: what you tried? you are asking someone to do it for you?

Comment: Firstly, thank you to the person who edited the post for me for formatting. Secondly, I don't even know where to start to use data from one JSON file to reference data from another JSON file.

Comment: SO basically, if *class* file has only 3 *levels*, you want to display in HTML those three -> merged with *master* file? What's your best try in jQuery you've done so far?

Comment: The "level"s are just the class levels at which a character of that class learns that skill. But yes, that's what I'd like to do. And, to be honest, I haven't tried any jQuery yet...I'm a complete novice to jQuery, and somewhat of a novice with JSON. My only experience with JSON is editing files from the Starbound game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/naxeti/1/edit)**

```
// GET MASTER FILE
$.getJSON( "db/master.json", function( data ) {

  var masterSkills = data.skills; // Store master Object
  // Now that we've read the master data let's see how many 
  // (cause you're working with Arrays)
  // of those skills has the Class 1 file

  // GET Class 1 FILE
  $.getJSON( "db/class.json", function( data ) {

     // Collect Class 1 skills (3 of them) adding data from
     // our stored masterSkills

     var rows = []; // Array to create rows
     $.each( data.skills, function( i, val ) { // 3 of them
       rows.push( "<tr>"+
                "<td>"+ val.name +"</td>"+
                "<td>Level "+ val.level +"</td>"+
                "<td>"+ masterSkills[i].cost +"</td>"+
                "<td>"+ masterSkills[i].desc +"</td>"+
                "</tr>" );
     });

     // Append collected data do some element ("body")
     $('<h1/>',{html: data.name }).appendTo("body");
     $( "<table/>", { html: rows.join("") }).appendTo("body");
  }); 

});
```

The above is usable ONLY if the sequence of both files matches the array count,
otherwise if you want to be sure to get **only the right data that matches the exact level** (in the case your *class* file has stored data in a non-incremental way) you'll have to change a bit the JSON structure, to prevent unnecessary loops to find an exact "Level" match. One way would be (master file):

```
{
  "skill1" : {
     "foo":"bar" 
  },
  "skill2" : {
     "blu":"bla"       
  },
}
```

now, instead of searching trough all "name" properties you can directly target the desired level and extract the values.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Thanks for answering...I'll have to try this later. Honestly, just looking at the code is making my head swim. Actually, scratch that, the "Collect class 1 skills adding data from our stored masterSkills" part stumps me.

Comment: @NateMcCloud `$.each( data.skills` will loop trough all the class.json skills passing (`val`) the value into the callback function. than you are simply concatenating the Array `rows` with keys kontaining string representations of the needed HTML TR structure. once you're done with looping, you crate a table `$( "<table/>", { html:` and to transform your comma separated Array back to string you join your array using `rows.join("")` and finally append the table to `body`. Yes, sounds scary... you need to explore a bit the jQuery docs and review  the basic of JS's Array handling.

Comment: Ahh, right, I see now. Forgot data.skills in the $.each part would be looping through the class skills, not the master skills. I initially thought you'd completely omitted the part where you looped through the class skills. Additionally, the order of the master skill list and the order of the class skills most definitely will NOT match exactly, especially since every class will be pulling from the same master list.

Comment: @NateMcCloud than you really need to consider my advice and modify the JSON structure, otherwise you'll be looping over and over multiple times to find a property value match. (Only the master file like in my example. use `"Skill XY"` as object property -> to represent that skill values) Your JS will end being much more readable and the response faster.

Comment: I was using something along the line of the structure used by Starbound JSON files, but I guess I can't be too picky. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I misunderstood your question, but you'll want to do something like this:

1. Store your master json file in on the server, e.g. `data.json`.
2. Either store everything else in the same file, like so: `{"classes": [ classes go here ]}`, or each in a separate file, like `class1.json`, `class2.json`, etc.
3. Then, use js to pull the data from the files to your html page, like so:

   `$.getJSON('data.json', function (data) { // do this for all your files
       // process your data here
   });`
4. Then, within the callbacks, use basic DOM manipulation to create your table, e.g. (a simplified example):

   `var html = $("<p>The skill's name: " + data["skills"][0]["name"]);
   $("#yourtable").append(html);`

EDIT: if you want to do this for each skill, it's as simple as

```
var skills = data["skills"];
$.each(skills, function (index) {
    // do your DOM stuff here (skills[index] is your skill)
});
```

That will iterate over each skill, and do the same thing for each one.

EDIT 2: here is the full code you asked for.

```
// assume class data is stored in files called [classname].json
var classname = "yourclass", masterfile = "master.json";
// fetch data from the master file
$.getJSON(masterfile, function (masterData) {
    // fetch data from your class file
    $.getJSON(classname + ".json", function (classData) {
        var skills = classData["skills"]
        // iterate over each skill in the class
        for(var i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
            var skill = skills[i];
            // iterate over each skill in the master file
            for(var j = 0; j < masterData["skills"].length; j++) {
                // check if the names of the skill in the class and the skill in the master file match
                if(masterData["skills"][j][name] === skill["name"]) {
                    // the skill names match
                    var s = masterData["skills"][j];
                    // s is now your skill variable, where s["cost"] is the cost, et cetera
                    // now, do your DOM manipulation using the skill data
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Something like that...but I would like for it to pull data from two different JSON files based on a common attribute...in this case, the skill name. The JS would pull, from each of the class's skills, the skill name and level learned from the class file, and the matching skill's description and cost from the master skill file, and format it into HTML.

Comment: I can give you the complete code you need, but I'd like you to try yourself first. If you struggle, then I'll show you how.

Comment: I know how to format the JSON data into HTML...what I don't understand is how to use data pulled from one JSON file to find and pull more data from another JSON file based on a common attribute. Again, like tables in a database that are linked by common headings.

Comment: I understand that. Well, now I do :P As I said, have a go yourself. I can tell you how right now if you want, but you should try it yourself first.

Comment: I give up. I've been trying to figure this out for a month, and I'm still no closer to the solution than I was when I started. Searching for the answer on Google produced no useful results.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/HJ8VkyHL Look at it if you want, or try again if you don't.

Comment: I will give that a try. Thank you so much for the help! I don't think I ever would have figured this out on my own.

Comment: No problem. Ask if you need any more help.